# headerBuilder not working in SignInScreen of firebase_ui_auth in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a widget to SignInScreen to Web app:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SignInScreen(
      providers: [EmailAuthProvider()],
      headerBuilder: (context, constraints, shrinkOffset) {
        return Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the red square should appear above the SignInScreen widget. But it doesn't appear - I see just a standard SignInScreen.

Sidebuilder works as expected - with red trianlge to the left.

I use `firebase_ui_auth: ^1.1.16`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand - headerBuilder doesn't work on web applications - only on mobiles.

`subtitleBuilder` / `footerBuilder` work as expected.